# Why is my State Array not updating even when I'm passing in a array to the useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-state

This is my `useEffect()` :

```
const [imagesArray, setImagesArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendering");
    let tempImagesArray = [];
    storageRef
      .listAll()
      .then((res) => {
        res._delegate.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
          projectStorage
            .ref(imageRef._location.path_)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
              //url is the URL of an image in the database. I have checked, IT is correct
              tempImagesArray.push(url);
            });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    setImagesArray([...imagesArray, ...tempImagesArray]);
    console.log("Temp images arr is", tempImagesArray); //["https://firebase....","https://firebase....", "https://firebase...."]
    console.log("Main images state arr is ", imagesArray); //[]
  }, []);
```

I'm adding URLs to `tempImagesArray`  and after I have added all URLs, I try to update the `imagesArray` using `setImagesArray` but when I console log `imagesArray`, it shows an empty array AND if I console log `tempImagesArray` it shows an array which is full of URLs!!!

Why is this happeneing and how do I fix this? Please help, I have been trying to solve this for hours

Comment: Try moving  setImagesArray([...imagesArray, ...tempImagesArray]); just below of tempImagesArray.push(url);

Tell me if it works

Comment: The `then` callback will run after you have already called `setImagesArray`. You cannot expect to get a value *now* when it is only available in the *future*.

Comment: `setImagesArray`  is asynchronous function so when you try to access `imagesArray` after immediately changing it will return previous value which in your case is blank array. 

So try to use `useEffect`

Comment: @fjplaurr IT WORKED!!! You are a savior 

Comment: @PriyankKachhela how is setImagesArray asynchronnous? Its not fetching anything! It's just changing the state!

Comment: What was happening is that all the block storageRef... is being executed asynchronously. That means that, by the time setImagesArray arrives, temImagesArray is still empty. That's why yo have to move it just where I said to make sure that they are executed synchronously, one after the other.

Comment: Please follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately